# Add channel to MNIST via transform?

Tags: pytorch, mnist, python-3.7, torchvision

I'm trying to use the MNIST dataset from `torchvision.datasets`.It seems to be provided as an `N x H x W (uint8)` (batch dimension, height, width) tensor. All the pytorch classes for working on images (for instance [`Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d)) however require a `N x C x H x W (float32)` tensor where `C` is the number of colour channels. I've tried to add add the [`ToTensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor) transform but that didn't add a color channel.

Is there a way using `torchvision.transforms` to add this additional dimension? For a raw `tensor` we could just do `.unsqueeze(1)` but that doesn't look like a very elegant solution. I'm just trying to do it the "proper" way.

Here is the failed conversion.

```
import torchvision
dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST("~/PyTorchDatasets/MNIST/", train=True, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(), download=True)
print(dataset.train_data[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a misconception: `dataset.train_data` is *not* affected by the specified `transform`, only the output of a `DataLoader(dataset,...)` will be. After checking `data` from

```
for data, _ in DataLoader(dataset):
    break
```

we can see that `ToTensor` actually does exactly what is desired.